# How to restore screen to normal size after turning off the MIUI optimization?

Tags: xiaomi, miui, developer-options, redmi, optimization

My phone is Xiaomi Redmi Note 9, how can I restore the screen size of my phone after turning off the MIUI optimization even if I turned it back on? Before i have small screen size and small fonts 'coz it's what i prefer and now they got bigger. Please help i don't know what to do.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Additional Settings > Accessibility > Vision > Display (or simply search for Display size) and change that setting if you have it to on and off, for example I had it on XS but it showed bigger, so I put it on S, saved it, then put it back on XS and it's back as it used to be.